# VTK file format error for VTK_Vertex

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am trying to visualize particle data in Paraview. I have no problem using the VTK file format PDF to visualize unstructured grid data (with 3 or 4 sided cells):

http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf

However, I am having trouble getting point data to load into paraview. A simple particle file (that doesn't work) follows:

```
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
<UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints=“2” NumberOfCells=“2”>
        <CellData Scalars="scalars">
            <DataArray type="Float64" Name=“Particle Strengths" NumberOfComponents="1" Format="ascii">
-0.174227       
-0.0716306  
            </DataArray>
        </CellData>
        <Points>
            <DataArray type="Float64" Name="Position" NumberOfComponents="3" Format="ascii">
0.867532    0.186254    -0.00153193 
1   0.157078    0   
            </DataArray>
        </Points>
        <Cells>
            <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" Format="ascii">
0   
1   
            </DataArray>
            <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" Format="ascii">
1
2
            </DataArray>
            <DataArray type=“UInt8” Name="types" Format="ascii">
1   
1       
            </DataArray>
        </Cells>
    </Piece>
</UnstructuredGrid>
```

For reference, I am getting this error when trying to load into paraview, which makes it sound like 2 is not an acceptable number of points. Any ideas?

```
ERROR: In /Users/kitware/Dashboards/MyTests/NightlyMaster/ParaViewSuperbuild- 
     Release-Python27/paraview/src/paraview/VTK/IO/XMLParser/vtkXMLParser.cxx, line 483
vtkXMLDataParser (0x7f848c224cf0): Error parsing XML in stream at line 3,
column 24, byte index 118: not well-formed (invalid token)


ERROR: In /Users/kitware/Dashboards/MyTests/NightlyMaster/ParaViewSuperbuild-
Release-Python27/paraview/src/paraview/VTK/IO/XML/vtkXMLReader.cxx, line 448
vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader (0x7f848c2a0d40): Error parsing input file.   
ReadXMLInformation aborting.


ERROR: In /Users/kitware/Dashboards/MyTests/NightlyMaster/ParaViewSuperbuild-
Release-Python27/paraview/src/paraview/VTK/Common/ExecutionModel/vtkExecutive.cxx, line 784
vtkPVCompositeDataPipeline (0x7f848c292a50): Algorithm
```

vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader(0x7f848c2a0d40) returned failure for request:
vtkInformation (0x7f848c224c80)
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 304502
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Request: REQUEST_INFORMATION
    ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
    FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0

Comment: It looks like you have edited your file in a text editor that uses "smart quotes." If you look at line 3, column 24, you will see that it points to the first  quote in NumberOfPoints="2". That quote, like many others in the text, is not the ASCII quote character with straight lines but an extended quote character with bent lines. There are several places in the text with those special slant-y quotes that look like ASCII quotes but are not. If you change those to be actual ASCII quotes and add a </VTKFile> closing tag at the end of the file, it should load correctly.

Comment: @KennethMoreland Thank you! Works without problem!